# How to extend Doctrine2' Entity Repository Constructor?

Tags: php, symfony, constructor, doctrine-orm

When re-writing the constructor in my entity manager, this doesn't work:

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function getUserFromKey()
    { 
// Rest of the function/class ..
```

Why ?
(I get massive erros from Doctrine ORM core)

Comment: Not to nitpick but you are extending EntityRepository and not EntityManager.  Two very different things.  You are not trying to actually do: $userRepo = new UserReporitory() are you?  That won't work at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doctrine [EntityRepository](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php) has some params in constructor, you need to copy it and past to parent constructor

```
/**
 * Initializes a new <tt>EntityRepository</tt>.
 *
 * @param EntityManager         $em    The EntityManager to use.
 * @param Mapping\ClassMetadata $class The class descriptor.
 */
public function __construct($em, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
{
    $this->_entityName = $class->name;
    $this->_em         = $em;
    $this->_class      = $class;
}
```

For example

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    function __construct($em, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
    {
        parent::__construct($em, $class);
        $this->CI =& get_instance(); // looks strange
    }
```

Comment: thanks, Ill try this. The `$this->CI =& get_instance();` is mandatory when working with CodeIgniter and its Librairies

Comment: I've tried and got an error message, probably linked to my struture: `Argument 2 passed to Entity\UserRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Entity\Mapping\ClassMetadata, instance of Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata given, called in /Sites/meetmyfriends-back/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php on line 689 and defined` When I add Entity/ before `\Mapping\ClassMetadata` the error message become ` [...] must be an instance of Entity\Entity\Mapping\ClassMetadata [...]` and so on .. apparently there is a problem with where my ORM is ?

Comment: My entities are in `/application/models/Entity` and Doctrine ORM is in `/application/librairies/Doctrine/ORM` even is my Doctrine.php file is in `application/librairies`.
In this file I'm using `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`

Comment: OK! I had it working passing `\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata $class`. Thanks !